# ImportError: cannot import name 'Affiliate' from partially initialized module 'affiliate.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting a circular import error in django and can't seem to solve it.
here's my models.py in affiliate(app)

```
from member.models import Member

class SubAffiliate(models.Model):
    member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here's my models.py in member(app)

```
from affiliate.models import Affiliate

class Member(models.Model):
    affiliates = models.ManyToManyField(Affiliate, blank=True, related_name="members_affiliate")
```

for solving the problem I tried importing like this

```
import affiliate.models
```

and there use it like this

```
affiliate.models.Affiliate
```

then I get this error `AttributeError: module 'affiliate' has no attribute 'models'`

what should I do to resolve this error. Thank You!

Comment: Your question doesn't include the full stack trace (*why not?*) but it is almost certain that your program is called `affiliate.py` and that is masking the module you are trying to import. Call your program something else.

Comment: I have 2 different apps. Member and Affiliate. and having this error while importing things into both models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two models can not import each other. You can work with a string literal in case you need to refer to another module's model:

```
# no import from member.models!

class SubAffiliate(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        'member.Member',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

and for the other `models.py` file, you can also work with a string with the `app_name.ModelName`:

```
# no import from affiliate.models

class Member(models.Model):
    affiliates = models.ManyToManyField(
        'affiliate.Affiliate',
        blank=True,
        related_name='members_affiliate'
    )
```